# How can I switch categories back to the non SEO-friendly URLs?

Tags: category, url-rewrite

This may seem weird, but I want to know how to stop using the SEO-friendly URLs for categories.

So instead of something like:

/apparel/shirts.html

I want

/catalog/category/view/s/shirts/id/188/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set this from admin panel.
Go to System => Configuration => Left sidebar, General => Web

here you can find the "Search Engines Optimization" tab. Set "Use Web Server Rewrites" to "No".

Thanks

Comment: Thanks!  I'm afraid this will cancel the web server rewrites for the product pages as well.  I'm guessing there is no way to just cancel this for categories, but not products?

Comment: Well this answers the question I originally asked, so I'm going to accept the answer.